# Lambda with Python and Boto3 has key error on list_virtual_mfa_devices

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am struggling to see how this has a key error.  I have run this on a single AWS account and it reports successfully all the users which do not have MFA.  Moving the Lambda to a child account and now assuming a role to retreive users without MFA, its failing on a key error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'User'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_mfa_function.py",
      28,
      "lambda_handler",
      "virtualEnabled.append(virtual['User']['UserName'])"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Checking the boto3 documentation for VirtualMFADevices i cannot see why this is now not working, returning to the single AWS account, it runs successfully, moving it to a child account causes a key failure

```
import boto3

sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::99999999:role/role",
    RoleSessionName="AssumedRoleSession2"
)
credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']
client=boto3.client(
    'iam',
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
)

def lambda_handler(context,event):

#    client                  = boto3.client('iam')
    sns                     = boto3.client('sns')
    response                = client.list_users()
    userVirtualMfa          = client.list_virtual_mfa_devices()
    mfaNotEnabled           = []
    virtualEnabled          = []
    physicalString          = ''

    # loop through virtual mfa to find users that actually have it
    for virtual in userVirtualMfa['VirtualMFADevices']:
        virtualEnabled.append(virtual['User']['UserName'])

    # loop through users to find physical MFA
    for user in response['Users']:
        userMfa  = client.list_mfa_devices(UserName=user['UserName'])

        if len(userMfa['MFADevices']) == 0:
            if user['UserName'] not in virtualEnabled:
                mfaNotEnabled.append(user['UserName']) 


    if len(mfaNotEnabled) > 0:
        physicalString = 'Physical & Virtual MFA is not enabled for the following users: \n\n' + '\n'.join(mfaNotEnabled)
    else:
        physicalString = 'All Users have Physical and Virtual MFA enabled'

    response = sns.publish(
        TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:1111111:sns',
        Message= physicalString,
        Subject='Enable MFA',
    )

    return mfaNotEnabled
```

Any help i would be very grateful
Thanks
Nick

---

Edit, 
Thanks for the replies, i have added some debugging.

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_mfa_function.py",
      27,
      "lambda_handler",
      "raise Exception(\"Invalid virtual %s\" % virtual)"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "Exception",
  "errorMessage": "Invalid virtual {u'SerialNumber': 'arn:aws:iam::11111111:mfa/jimmy.dave4@foobar.com'}"
}

Get
```

ting somewhere now.  Cheers to those who replied

Comment: The `User` in the response represents an IAM user. Is it possible that the device is associated with the root user and hence there's no IAM user to report on? Also, not sure what you mean by child account - is this an AWS Organization?

Answer (score 1):

Start debugging the dictionary object inside your lambda handler:

```
def lambda_handler(context,event):
    userVirtualMfa = client.list_virtual_mfa_devices()

    print(f"{'VirtualMFADevices' in userVirtualMfa.keys() = }")
    print(f"{'UserName' in userVirtualMfa['VirtualMFADevices'].keys() = }")

    try:
        for virtual in userVirtualMfa['VirtualMFADevices']:
            virtualEnabled.append(virtual['User']['UserName'])
    except:
        print("'UserName' is not a valid key")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Exception has now been triggered:

Comment: Great. And what was the output fro the above 2 print statements ? Which keys got printed out ?

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting very useful output; just that 'User' isn't in the dict that you're looking for. It might be worth adding some error checking:

```
    # untested
    for virtual in userVirtualMfa['VirtualMFADevices']:
        if 'User' not in virtual or 'UserName' not in virtual['User']:
           raise Exception("Invalid virtual %s" % virtual)

        virtualEnabled.append(virtual['User']['UserName'])
```

or alternatively some exception handling

```
    # untested
    for virtual in userVirtualMfa['VirtualMFADevices']:
        try:
             virtualEnabled.append(virtual['User']['UserName']) 
        except KeyError as kerr:
            raise KeyError('Key %s not found in %s', kerr, virtual)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Exception has now been triggered: